# How to create a MongoDB document containing objects and arrays, as well as the corresponding scheme in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I need to save in a `mongodb` database data like this:

```
{
    name: "Just a name",
    questions: [
        {
            question: "Question 1",
            answerOptions: [
                {id: 0, text: "answer 1"},
                {id: 1, text: "answer 2"},
                {id: 2, text: "answer 3"}
            ],
            correctOptions: [ 0, 2 ]
        },
        {
            question: "Question 2",
            correctAnswers: [ "answer", "another answer" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

1. Is it possible to save the data in one collection or should I apply data decomposition and save this data in a several related collections (main, answers, answeroptions, etc) ?
2. If it is possible to save it in one collection how could Mongoose schema look like? I mean I don't understand how to describe objects and arrays of objects as fields in Mongoose schema

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1. yes looking at your use case it is possible to save data in one collection as data is not hierarchical. Mongo is not for joins and you will have to handle that in your code.

2. Here is what I am using for my schema. Document contains fields like array of objects and other types -

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var fieldFive = new mongoose.Schema({
    someField1: String,
    _id:false
});


var someArrayObject = new mongoose.Schema({
    someField1: String,
    someField2: String,
    someField3: false
});


var SampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  fieldOne: {type:String, required: true},
  fieldTwo: String,
  fieldThree: [someArrayObject],
  fieldFour: {someOtherField1:[String], someOtherField2:[String], someOtherField3:[String]},
  fieldFive: {type:{}, ref:fieldFive},
  createdAt: {type: Date},
  updatedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},

});

module.exports = SampleSchema;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One more question: how add `required: true;` to the `someOtherField1` field description?